# How to remove an error pop up in worksheet change event?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet change event macro that hides certain rows based on a given cell value.  My macro works perfectly except when you have to delete data out of a cell that is contain within the rows in the macro. This pops up the Type Mismatch error.  Is there a way to prevent this error from happening?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

 Sheets("Parallelism").Rows("6:22").EntireRow.Hidden = False

 If Target.Address = ("$J$4") And Target.Value = "LDS Parallelism" Then
     Sheets("Parallelism").Rows("14:21").EntireRow.Hidden = True
 
 ElseIf Target.Address = ("$J$4") And Target.Value = "Mitutoyo Parallelism" Then
    Sheets("Parallelism").Rows("6:13").EntireRow.Hidden = True

ElseIf Target.Address = ("$J$4") And Target.Value = "Select Method" Then
    Sheets("Parallelism").Rows("6:21").EntireRow.Hidden = True

 End If
End Sub
```

Comment: When you delete, are you deleting from a single cell or several cells at once? If it's several cells, then you can't check a single value from the target because the target is now a range of cells with multiple values.

Comment: Sorry for the late response but it can be either one cell or multiple cells.  It depends on the user at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work for you:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Dim rTarget As Range
    Set rTarget = Me.Range("J4")
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, rTarget) Is Nothing Then
        Me.Rows("6:22").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Select Case rTarget.Value
            Case "LDS Parallelism":         Me.Rows("14:21").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Case "Mitutoyo Parallelism":    Me.Rows("6:13").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Case "Select Method":           Me.Rows("6:21").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End Select
    End If
    
End Sub
```